# Accessing values of pointers to large array

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to C and StackOverflow.

I'm trying to implement the solution to this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624027/how-to-create-a-fast-huge-union-array-without-wasting-memory-in-c](http:////stackoverflow.com/questions/34624027/how-to-create-a-fast-huge-union-array-without-wasting-memory-in-c) in Visual Studio-2015.  The following is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "malloc.h"
#include "inttypes.h"

#define RESERVED_BYTES 2147483648

typedef union {
    void *pv;
    char *pc;
    uint8_t *pu8;
    uint16_t *pu16;
} parray_type;

int main()
{
    parray_type parray;
    parray.pv = calloc(RESERVED_BYTES, 1);

    // last element in allocated buffer for each type
    char c = parray.pc[RESERVED_BYTES - 1];
    uint8_t u8 = parray.pu8[RESERVED_BYTES - 1];
    uint16_t u16 = parray.pu16[RESERVED_BYTES / 2 - 1];

    // first element in allocated buffer for each type
    char c_2= parray.pc[0];
    uint8_t u8_2 = parray.pu8[0];
    uint16_t u16_2 = parray.pu16[0];

    printf("c='%c' (%d)  u8='0x%x' (%d) u16='%h' (%d)\n", c, c, u8, u8, u16, u16);
    printf("c='%c' (%d)  u8='0x%x' (%d) u16='%h' (%d)\n", c_2, c_2, u8_2, u8_2, u16_2, u16_2);

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles OK, but when I try to run it I get the following error on the assignment of `char c = parray.pc[RESERVED_BYTES - 1];`.  The error is `Unhandled exception at 0x012717F8 in TstLrgArr.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x7FFFFFFF.`  When I comment out the three lines assigning c, u8 and u16 I get the same error on the assignment of c_2 except the access violation is reading location 0x00000000.

The output I think is was expecting was 2 lines of the following:
`c='' (0)   u8='0x00' (0)   u16='' (0)`

What did I do wrong, or is this some limitation of VS-2015?

Comment: I would start by investigating the call to ``calloc()``: its return value, and if any error flag is set (errno and/or GetLastError). You are trying to allocate 2 Gb at once - this is quite a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  The error is `Not enough space` so the pointer is 00000000.  I thought the point of the solution was that it allowed arrays up to 2 Gb.  Was the solution incorrect?

Comment: The only (simple) way to get a 2 Gb allocation on Windows is to use 64-bit. (32-bit processes can use other functions to raise the limit to 3 Gb but I very much doubt they can allocate 2 Gb at once anyway). So: to use the answer you refer to, compile for 64-bit.

Comment: @Tibo  Thanks again for the tip.  I didn't know how to compile for 64-bit but now I do and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum size that `calloc` can allocate depends on the platform on which you are running. Your array size is possibly far to big `#define RESERVED_BYTES 2147483648`. `calloc` will possibly return `NULL`.

Add NULL pointer test to your code.

```
 parray.pv = calloc(RESERVED_BYTES, 1);
 if ( parray.pv == NULL )
 {
     // ... add print error ...
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I thought the calloc(RESERVED_BYTES, 1) would initialize the pointer. ?

Comment: As I noted above, the error was "Not enough space".  Basically I just copied the code from this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624027/how-to-create-a-fast-huge-union-array-without-wasting-memory-in-c so I thought it would work OK.